# Upgrade to magento 2.3.2 suddenly shows wrong / duplicate labels on default checkout

Tags: magento2

I upgraded magento 2.3.0 to magento 2.3.2 and now it shows the tooltip label and a strange street address: line 1 label in the default checkout. Do not want to hide it with css but a real solution would be great.

[image]

Comment: This happens with me too, but don't mind after hours of digging I've to hide them with `css`.

Comment: not possible for me as the street label css is also used for my payment method labels :-(

Comment: @SandervanZuidam i have same issue facing someday ago when magento 2.2.5 to 2.3.2 upgrade

Comment: @SandervanZuidam Why you need `Street Address: Line 1` for the payment method while you have `Street Address *` for that....